# Proper Spelling

Tags: spelling

Is it OK to write "into" like "in to", etc. ? I found it in the book `<<The Golden Compass>>`. I sometimes forget to connect the two parts, so I was just wondering.

Comment: Could you provide the context for "in to?"

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the sentence. I'm pretty sure it meant into.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what this question is getting at. As [covered by ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/) long before ELL even existed, **into** is a specific one-word preposition. And **in to** are two words which can validly occur consecutively in various different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases it's going to be "into" meaning "going within." Without the context, my best guess of how this is being used is something like "He goes in to see the doctor" where "to" is not associated with "in" but really part of "to see."